# Flutter web flavor

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a Flutter web app that uses firebase and I have two firebase projects(dev and prod).
I'll like to set up Flavors for this project(just web no mobile).

In mobile, I can use different `GoogleService-Info.plist` or `google-services.json` files for either flavor but I could not find anyway to do this on the web app as the configuration is done in the `index.html` file. Is there any way to do this? Maybe have different HTML files and specify which of them to be bundled while running the app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebase SDK auto-configuration. By relying on the reserved Hosting URL, you can deploy the same code to multiple Firebase projects.

On each of your Firebase projects, go to Project Overview -> Project settings. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v17ux.png)

Under "Your apps" select your web app. If you haven't, link your web app to a firebase hosting site.

In Firebase SDK snippet, select the **automatic** option. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH8kT.png)

Replace your current firebase configuration on **index.html** to:

```
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="/__/firebase/7.21.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="/__/firebase/7.21.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Firebase -->
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

That's it, this will allow you to use the same **index.html** for different flavors.

[More Info here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls#sdk_auto-configuration)

Answer (score -1):

See [Flutter Firebase - Setting different deployment targets for iOS, Android, and Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66560305/flutter-firebase-setting-different-deployment-targets-for-ios-android-and-w/66560306#66560306).

This explains doing flavors for iOS and Android and Firebase SDK auto-configuration for the Web.